# Simulating a random packet routing algorithm and printing packet statistics in Java

Tags: java, networking, simulation

I have this short program for simulating a random packet routing algorithm:

**Packet.java**

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.network;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class implements a packet being transmitted in the network.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 23, 2016)
 */
public class Packet {

    private final int sourceNetworkNodeId;
    private final int targetNetworkNodeId;

    private final List<NetworkNode> history = new ArrayList<>();
    private int cycles;

    public Packet(final int id, 
                  final int sourceNetworkNodeId, 
                  final int targetNetworkNodeId) {
        this.sourceNetworkNodeId = sourceNetworkNodeId;
        this.targetNetworkNodeId = targetNetworkNodeId;
    }

    public boolean isDelivered() {
        if (history.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        return history.get(history.size() - 1).getId() == targetNetworkNodeId;
    }

    public final void mark(final NetworkNode networkNode) {
        history.add(networkNode);
    }

    public final void incrementCycleCounter() {
        cycles++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("[")
          .append(sourceNetworkNodeId)
          .append(" -> ")
          .append(targetNetworkNodeId)
          .append("; cycles: ")
          .append(cycles)
          .append("; history: [");

        final Map<Integer, Integer> map = compressPath(history);

        final Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator = 
                map.entrySet().iterator();

        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = iterator.next();

            if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
                sb.append(entry.getKey());
            } else {
                sb.append(entry.getKey())
                  .append("(")
                  .append(entry.getValue())
                  .append(")");
            }
        }

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = iterator.next();

            sb.append(", ");

            if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
                sb.append(entry.getKey());
            } else {
                sb.append(entry.getKey())
                  .append("(")
                  .append(entry.getValue())
                  .append(")");
            }
        }

        return sb.append("]]").toString();
    }

    private Map<Integer, Integer> compressPath(final List<NetworkNode> path) {
        final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (final NetworkNode networkNode : path) {
            final int networkNodeId = networkNode.getId();
            map.put(networkNodeId, map.getOrDefault(networkNodeId, 0) + 1);
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

**NetworkNode.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.network;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class implements a simulated network node. Each node maintains a queue 
 * of packets that have been received but not yet sent away. 
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 23, 2016)
 */
public class NetworkNode {

    private final int id;
    private final List<NetworkNode> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Deque<Packet> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final Random random = new Random();

    private int maximumQueueLength;

    public NetworkNode(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public final void connect(final NetworkNode node) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(node, "The input node is null.");

        if (!neighbors.contains(node)) {
            neighbors.add(node);
            node.neighbors.add(this);
        }
    }

    public final List<NetworkNode> getNeighborList() {
        return Collections.<NetworkNode>unmodifiableList(neighbors);
    }

    public final int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void offetPacket(final Packet packet) {
        queue.add(packet);
    }

    public void sendPacket() {
        maximumQueueLength = Math.max(maximumQueueLength, queue.size());

        for (final Packet packet : queue) {
            packet.incrementCycleCounter();
            packet.mark(this);
        }

        final Iterator<Packet> iterator = queue.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Packet packet = iterator.next();

            if (packet.isDelivered()) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            final Packet packet = queue.removeFirst();
            final NetworkNode nextNetworkNode = randomNeighbor();
            nextNetworkNode.queue.addLast(packet);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[ID = " + id + "; maximum queue length: " +
               maximumQueueLength + "]";
    }

    private final NetworkNode randomNeighbor() {
        return neighbors.get(random.nextInt(neighbors.size()));
    }
}
```

**Main.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.network;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    private static final int NETWORK_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_LINKS = 50;
    private static final int PACKETS = 30;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<NetworkNode> network = createRandomNetwork(NETWORK_SIZE,
                                                              NUMBER_OF_LINKS);
        final List<Packet> packets = createInitialPackets(network,
                                                          PACKETS);

        while (somePacketsUndelivered(packets)) {
            for (final NetworkNode networkNode : network) {
                networkNode.sendPacket();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("=== Packet statistics ===");
        packets.forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("=== Node statistics ===");
        network.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static boolean somePacketsUndelivered(final List<Packet> packets) {
        for (final Packet packet : packets) {
            if (!packet.isDelivered()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static List<NetworkNode> createRandomNetwork(final int size,
                                                         final int edges) {
        final List<NetworkNode> network = new ArrayList<>(size);

        for (int id = 0; id < NETWORK_SIZE; ++id) {
            network.add(new NetworkNode(id));
        }

        final Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < edges; ++i) {
            network.get(random.nextInt(NETWORK_SIZE))
                   .connect(network.get(random.nextInt(NETWORK_SIZE)));
        }

        return network;
    }

    private static List<Packet>
         createInitialPackets(final List<NetworkNode> network,
                              final int packets) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final List<Packet> packetList = new ArrayList<>(packets);

        for (int id = 0; id < packets; ++id) {
            final NetworkNode source = 
                    network.get(random.nextInt(network.size()));

            final NetworkNode target = 
                    network.get(random.nextInt(network.size()));

            final Packet packet = new Packet(id,
                                             source.getId(),
                                             target.getId());
            packetList.add(packet);
            source.offetPacket(packet);
        }

        return packetList;
    }
}
```

As always, any critique is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean isDelivered() {
    if (history.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    return history.get(history.size() - 1).getId() == targetNetworkNodeId;
}
```

No need for explicitly handling empty case here, just combine:

```
return !history.isEmpty() && history.get(history.size() - 1).getId() == targetNetworkNodeId;
```

---

```
        if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
            sb.append(entry.getKey());
        } else {
            sb.append(entry.getKey())
              .append("(")
              .append(entry.getValue())
              .append(")");
        }
```

Take what is similar and extract out of the if-statement...

```
sb.append(entry.getKey());
if (entry.getValue() == 1) {

} else {
    sb.append("(")
      .append(entry.getValue())
      .append(")");
}
```

You're left with an empty if, so invert it and remove the else.

```
sb.append(entry.getKey());
if (entry.getValue() != 1) {
    sb.append("(")
      .append(entry.getValue())
      .append(")");
}
```

The entirety of this is duplicate code, however - you have an if-statement containing this, and a while-loop containing this. Extract to method `appendEntryToStringBuilder`:

```
private void appendEntryToStringBuilder(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry, StringBuilder sb){
    sb.append(entry.getKey());
    if (entry.getValue() != 1) {
        sb.append("(")
          .append(entry.getValue())
          .append(")");
    }
}
```

---

```
public void offetPacket
```

Did you mean `offerPacket`?

---

```
network.get(random.nextInt(network.size()));
```

This, or something like it, is used A LOT through out your code. Consider making a method `getRandomNode(Random rngSource)` which returns a random node.

Answer (score -1):

It is almost perfect. There are a few things I would like to point out, correct me if I am wrong:

MAIN CLASS ONLY:

1. You have some constants that seem unnecessary, because they are only used once in the class and are private

   ```
   private static final int NETWORK_SIZE = 10;
   private static final int NUMBER_OF_LINKS = 50;
   private static final int PACKETS = 30;

   public static void main(final String[] args) {
       final List<NetworkNode> network = createRandomNetwork(NETWORK_SIZE,
                                                             NUMBER_OF_LINKS);
       final List<Packet> packets = createInitialPackets(network,
                                                         PACKETS);
   ```

   could be simply replaced with:

   ```
   private static final int NETWORK_SIZE = 10;

   public static void main(final String[] args){
       final List<NetworkNode> network = createRandomNetwork(NETWORK_SIZE, 50);
       final List<Packet> packets = createInitialPackets(network, 30);
   ```

   Because the NUMBER_OF_LINKS and PACKETS constants are only used once.
2. Your method variables (inside the brackets) are used purposely in the `createInitialPacket` method but not in the `createRandomNetwork` method. I would change:

   ```
   private static List<NetworkNode> createRandomNetwork(final int size,
                                                    final int edges) {
       final List<NetworkNode> network = new ArrayList<>(size);

       for (int id = 0; id < NETWORK_SIZE; ++id) {
           network.add(new NetworkNode(id));
       }

       final Random random = new Random();

       for (int i = 0; i < edges; ++i) {
           network.get(random.nextInt(NETWORK_SIZE))
              .connect(network.get(random.nextInt(NETWORK_SIZE)));
       }

       return network;
   }
   ```

   into:

   ```
   private static List<NetworkNode> createRandomNetwork(final int size,
                                                    final int edges) {
       final List<NetworkNode> network = new ArrayList<>(size);

       for (int id = 0; id < size; ++id) {
           network.add(new NetworkNode(id));
       }

       final Random random = new Random();

       for (int i = 0; i < edges; ++i) {
           network.get(random.nextInt(size))
              .connect(network.get(random.nextInt(size)));
       }

       return network;
   }
   ```

   and if you do that step you could do back to point 1 and remove the NETWORK_SIZE constant in the same way.

ALL CLASSES:

3. It is always good to give both ends of your list a type.

   (constants in order from top to bottom)
   Packet.java:

   ```
   private final List<NetworkNode> history = new ArrayList<NetworkNode>();

   final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
   ```

   NetworkNode.java:

   ```
   private final List<NetworkNode> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
   private final Deque<Packet> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
   ```

   Main.java

   ```
   final List<NetworkNode> network = new ArrayList<NetworkNode>(size);
   final List<Packet> packetList = new ArrayList<Packet>(packets);
   ```

As I said above, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Point 3: I completely disagree with this, it's a bothersome effort and doesn't add any new information; my IDE will warn me that the declaration is useless; the only time I'd like to see this is if the type specified DOESN'T match the type of the variable it's going to be put in.

Comment: Also disagreeing with point 1 because that's not a constructor, it's a main method! It's an in-code configuration file and values like that should be constants because then you can infer more sense from them than without the constants.

Comment: Point 2a is correct; I'd say it's a possible bug, but the comment that you can then remove `NETWORK_SIZE` is misguided to me. All in all, you've got 1 point that seems to make sense, and the rest just plain... doesn't.

Comment: I never said that Point 1 was a constructor. Because the constants are only used once, all you are really doing is giving names to numbers. If the numbers are going to be the same, why have a constant for them?

Comment: And as for point 3 you are probably right, but I try to stay on the good side of my IDE.

Comment: "If the numbers are going to be the same, why have a constant for them?" because they might not? That's why you make constants. Because you might want to change the values to try out different things & test cases.